# Deploy angular application on local server

Tags: angular, build

I would like to deploy my angular 2 application on a local tomcat server.

I have executed npm run build command and I have copied the folder dist in to my root folder in my server tomcat.

When I run with the root URL http://localhost:8080 my application start but impossible to access to another route, for example http://localhost:8080/login return a 404 not found error.

I have no problem with my routes when I test with the command npm start. Do you have an idea where can to be the problem ?

Comment: You either need to set `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]` or configure Tomcat to support HTML5 pushState.

Comment: In my import I have already exactly this...  and else what is pushState ?

Comment: Without `useHash: true` you can have URLs without `#` (where the route paths came after `#`) like `http://example.com/route1/route2` vs `http://example.com/#/route1/route2`, but the former only works when the server plays along and returns `index.html` for all unknown paths.

Comment: how did you set the <base> tag in your index.html?

Comment: I try npm run build with <base href="/">

Comment: and for example http://localhost:8080/login exist in my routes list but I have a 404 error on the server